# Remove border in td ( more!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm getting old code in the company and the same in this table do not have time today to switch to DIV so I need some help ...

The class "`Mensagem`" has an edge that is to be displayed only when there is an answer to the user who will be the inerida lblResposta .... but when we load the page border is displayed without having any text inside how can I solve this case ....

Note: refactoring needs to be simple because it has over 500 pages with this error.

CSS

```
.TB_Mensagem {
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;
 width: 98%;
}
.Mensagem {
 border: 2px dotted; border-color: # ff7838;
 color: # ff7838; 
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 10px;
 line-height: 15px;
 padding-left: 5px; 
 padding-top: 2px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="TB_Mensagem">
 <tr>
  <td class="Mensagem"> 
   <asp:Label ID="lblResposta" runat="server"> </ asp: Label> 
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$('.Message').css('border', 'none');` this should work.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, possible? ;)

Comment: Interstingly, this question is closed as a duplicate of another one, which in turn is closed as "too localised".  Yet this question has valid answers and the linked one doesn't have any.

Comment: @AleksG the question isn't clear too. Whether he wants a CSS solution or a jQuery one.

Comment: @AleksG A duplicate is a duplicate. If the OP wants answer, they can resolve it in the original question, by providing a better explanation. Not creating another question with the same content

Comment: @Ian I'm not suggesting that it's wrong to close duplicates - it's just that it could make more sense to close the other one as the duplicate of this.  It's too late now, anyway.

Comment: @AleksG Ahh I see what you're saying. At the same time, it would encourage people to do the same thing - recreate a question because their original didn't get any answers because it was poor in the first place. But I doubt many people would catch on and realize that what was happening here anyways :)

Comment: sorry, i need a solution.
May be in Jquery or CSS that faster :)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**  re-reading your question, this shouldn't fit your needs.

You can use only CSS (CSS3) using `:empty` pseudo class:

http://jsfiddle.net/zReBX/

```
.Message:empty{display:none} /* or Messagem depending where is your typo! */
```

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td.Mensangem').filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.innerHTML) === ""
    }).css('border-style', 'none');
});
```

Comment: just about to post the same :), IMHO it is the right solution :)

Comment: I have to arrrumar all pages :( 
but is a solution!

Comment: i'm watching you roasted ;)

Comment: @Omar  lol, i hope you have forgotten this topic... ;)

Comment: Never forget, never forgive! lol

Comment: Sorry i don't understand: are you asking me to debug your website? Try code i have posted following last edit, it should work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with css alone. This can, however, be easily dealt with using javascript (and jQuery).  With jQuery you can add something like this on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td.Mensangem:empty').css('border-style','none');
});
```

Comment: +1 but maybe you should explain too how to reshow it when label filled

Comment: @roasted I don't see anything that would suggest that the content will change once the page has loaded.  If on another page load the content is not empty, then the border will be displayed.

Comment: You are right Alex, i just have hard time to understand exactly what OP wants

Comment: @roasted Fair enough, me too :) I've had enough experience trying to understand what non-native folks say in English :)

Answer (score 0):

table td has a class of "Messagem", but the CSS you posted is for .Message

anyways, try:

```
table tr td.Messagem {border:none !important;}
```

Comment: He wants a solution using jQuery not CSS.

Comment: @Omar  are you the OP? How do you know that?

Comment: i might have mis-read your question.

Comment: @roasted read the question thoroughly, and the tags :)

Comment: @Omar ya, i see CSS in the tags list, don't you?

Comment: @roasted I do, jQuery involving CSS.

Comment: @Omar You don't seem to understand what Tags are for...

Comment: @lan maybe, are you free to give me some of your experience in reading tags?

Comment: @Omar I didn't say anything about reading tags. You seem to be able to do that. Tags are not meant to signify what needs to be used in the solution. They're there just to categorize what the question is about or may include. Just because they have a jQuery tag doesn't mean jQuery is **required** in the answer. If they really want jQuery to be the solution, they can specify it in the question itself

Comment: @lan I know, @ AleksG and I, understood that he wants a jQuery solution on how to dynamically change CSS. @ laima and @ roasted understood the contrary. The OP isn't clear, however, tags sometimes give you a hint of what the OP wants.

Comment: @Omar I'm sorry but none of that makes sense to me. No one "realized" the OP wants a jQuery solution, because they don't say that. If it can be done without jQuery, it's just as valid of a solution. Depending on what the OP actually wants to happen (that's the confusing part to me), it can be accomplished in any way. Basic JavaScript, jQuery, CSS, etc. There's no restriction on what the solution can be unless the OP explicitly says so. The tags mean nothing in terms of how the answers are **required** to solve it. Sometimes, the OP will say "CSS only solution", in which case it must be honored

Comment: @lan I got your point. My apologies to Laima, roasted and you.

Comment: @Omar No apologies needed! I just like to be open-minded with questions. Too often what they are asking for isn't the best way to go about it anyways :)

Comment: @lan you're right, we should be flexible and open to any suggestion :)